# Pegar elemento em um array json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Preciso pegar o elemento `authorDisplayName` desse array `json`. Ele é o retorno de uma requisição `ajax`. Como pegar só o elemento com `jquery` ou `javascript`?

```
 "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
 "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/chdu9X44b3BNrN9QUEyKNGH_eiA\"",
 "id": "z12ts1iicov0ybbex22syzij4tuwyrxyk04",
 "snippet": {
  "channelId": "id",
  "videoId": "id",
  "topLevelComment": {
   "kind": "youtube#comment",
   "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/gKHFh_4gWxRa4aGZKqb5E1DJnww\"",
   "id": "z12ts1iicov0ybbex22syzij4tuwyrxyk04",
   "snippet": {
    "authorDisplayName": "Nome do autor",
    "authorProfileImageUrl": "imagem",
    "authorChannelUrl": "LINK",
    "authorChannelId": {
     "value": "UCLw8RgF4mQXkA_-ZCXAAyIQ"
    },
    "channelId": "UCIwspRtKNszHhIhl36gREjQ",
    "videoId": "VYw3eYIOJ08",
    "textDisplay": "",
    "textOriginal": "r",
    "canRate": true,
    "viewerRating": "none",
    "likeCount": 0,
    "moderationStatus": "likelySpam",
    "publishedAt": "2016-10-05T19:23:16.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-10-05T19:23:16.000Z"
   }
  },
  "canReply": true,
  "totalReplyCount": 0,
  "isPublic": true
 }
}
```

Meu codigo esta assim

```
$(document).on('click','.enviarComentario', function(){                                         
            var comentario = $('.comentbox').val();
            var id = $(this).attr('videoId');           
            $.ajax({
                    type:'post',            
                    url: 'enviarComentario.php',
                    data : { "comentario" : comentario, "idVideo" : id},
                    success: function (e) {                     
                        alert(e);
                        var res = e;
                        alert(res);
                        var authorDisplayName = res.snippet.channelId;
                        alert(authorDisplayName);
                        var comentarios = $('.comentariosLista').html();        
                        $('.comentariosLista').html("");
                        $('.comentariosLista').html('<div class="media">'+
                                '<div class="media-left">'+
                                    '<a href="#">'+
                                    '<img class="media-object" src="'+res.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorProfileImageUrl+'" alt="...">'+
                                    '</a>'+
                                '</div>'+
                                '<div class="media-body">'+
                                    '<h4 class="media-heading">'+
                                        '<strong>'+e.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorDisplayName+'</strong>'+
                                    '</h4>'+comentario+'</div></div>');                                                                  
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('n deu comentario');
                    }
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: Talvez a sua requisição $.ajax não esteja entendendo que o seu resultado é um JSON. Você pode forçar isso usando `'dataType': 'json'` logo abaixo do `type: post`.

Comment: A e não esqueça de utilizar no Google Chrome ou Firefox, a aba `Network` do Developer Tools assim você consegue "enxergar" como a requisição está vindo de seu servidor, por nada tem algum erro de PHP ali retornando um JSON mal formado.

Comment: Aparentemente tua resposta está sendo tratada como String. Tenta dar um var json = JSON.parse(res)
var authorDisplayName = json.snippet.channelId;

Answer (score 1):

O caminho dentro do objeto é `snippet > topLevelComment > snippet > authorDisplayName`. Não parece uma array, mas sim um objeto. Se este objeto está dentro de uma array, então tens de iterar a array primeiro e a cada iteração podes fazer como tenho em baixo onde chamei `res` ao objeto.

```
var authorDisplayName = res.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorDisplayName;
```

```js
var res = {
    "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
    "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/chdu9X44b3BNrN9QUEyKNGH_eiA\"",
    "id": "z12ts1iicov0ybbex22syzij4tuwyrxyk04",
    "snippet": {
        "channelId": "id",
        "videoId": "id",
        "topLevelComment": {
            "kind": "youtube#comment",
            "etag": "\"I_8xdZu766_FSaexEaDXTIfEWc0/gKHFh_4gWxRa4aGZKqb5E1DJnww\"",
            "id": "z12ts1iicov0ybbex22syzij4tuwyrxyk04",
            "snippet": {
                "authorDisplayName": "Nome do autor",
                "authorProfileImageUrl": "imagem",
                "authorChannelUrl": "LINK",
                "authorChannelId": {
                    "value": "UCLw8RgF4mQXkA_-ZCXAAyIQ"
                },
                "channelId": "UCIwspRtKNszHhIhl36gREjQ",
                "videoId": "VYw3eYIOJ08",
                "textDisplay": "",
                "textOriginal": "r",
                "canRate": true,
                "viewerRating": "none",
                "likeCount": 0,
                "moderationStatus": "likelySpam",
                "publishedAt": "2016-10-05T19:23:16.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2016-10-05T19:23:16.000Z"
            }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
    }
};
var authorDisplayName = res.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorDisplayName;
alert(authorDisplayName);
```

Comment: Vlw, mas nao funconou aki. Se eu tenho dar um alert aparece esse erro: TypeError: Cannot read property 'topLevelComment' of undefined. Por que será?

Comment: @Thiago podes colocar na pergunta o código jQuery ou JavaScritp nativo onde recebes o ajax?

Comment: Adicionei amigo

Comment: @Thiago o que dá `console.log(typeof e, Array.isArray(e), Object.keys(e));` na primeira linha desse sucesso do ajax?

Comment: Apareceu isso : String false ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92"…]

Comment: @Thiago ok, então e o que dá `console.log(typeof JSON.parse(e), Array.isArray(JSON.parse(e)), Object.keys(JSON.parse(e)));`?

Comment: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: @Thiago isso está com mau aspeto... ao ajax retorna uma string mal formatada e não pode ser usada como JSON. Como estás a enviar isso no servidor?

Comment: O que aparece no seu console, se vc fizer isso no retorno do success?
`console.log(e.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.authorDisplayName) `

Comment: Experimente fazer `console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, '  '));` e veja a estrutura real do objeto que está sendo retornado.

Comment: O alert não é recomendado para exibir estruturas de objetos. Prefira o resultado no console do navegador.

Comment: @IvanFerrer oi! As perguntas são para o Thiago?

Comment: Sim @Sergio, para o Thiago.

Comment: @Thiago ^ o IvanFerrer escreveu-te